# Gran Turismo Sport Editions

Tags: version-differences, gran-turismo-sport

I've ordered GT Sport "Day One Edition", however, right after that, I noticed, there are a few more editions of the game including "Digital Deluxe Edition".

Each edition comes with "additional" cars. Does it mean those cars are simply "unlocked" or players who Deluxe edition will have more cars than those who bought normal edition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cars bought with an upgraded edition are yours. They're not just unlocked, you get them directly into your garage and can use them right away.

They can also be bought in the manufacturers' sections in the Brand Central, if you don't own a Digital Deluxe Edition. The Prices are between 450.000 and 1.000.000 Credits for each of them.

The cars involved are:

> - Mazda LM55 Vision GT
> - Mitsubishi Lancer Gr.B Rally Car
> - Subaru WRX Gr.B Rally Car
> - SRT Tomahawk Vision GT
> - Ford Mustang Gr.B Rally Car
> - Ford Focus Gr.B Rally Car
> - Audi R18 TDI
> - Audi Sport Quattro S1 Pikes Peak ‘87
> - Peugeot RCZ Gr.B Rally Car
> - Toyota FT-1 Vision GT Group 3
> - GT-R NISMO GT3 N24 Schulze Motorsport
> - Corvette C7 Gr.3
> - Livery Sticker Package
> - Chrome Helmet
> - 2.000.000 Credits

Comment: What I meant exactly is that, can I also unlock these cars by playing game and getting in-game currency, or I will simply have less cars available in the whole game ?

Comment: @user1165499 yes, they can. I edited my answer to reflect that now, too.

Comment: @dly If you buy the limited edition, used... do you still get the extra cars?

Comment: @Joe the limited edition extras come with separate serial keys. If the previous owner redeemed them you can't get them anymore.